# javafx 2 TableView. Convert x,y into row and col indexes

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I want to display in a Tooltip some row-specific information when the user moves the mouse over a table row. I need a way to convert x,y coordinates into row (and col) indexes.

Comment: you can assign tooltips to cells and don't bother about coordinates